# How can I include jars in my WAR to be deployed to Glassfish?

Tags: java, jar, glassfish, war, java-web-start

I have jars in the main webapp of a WAR. They are being deployed as the dependencies of a Java Web Start app client, along with a JNLP.

I get a lot of class loader exceptions in Glassfish when I try to deploy it.

Is there a way to tell the WAR to ignore those jars?

Or even better, to have the JNLP work with a zip of the dependencies? (If I zip them, it deploys fine).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the jars deploy just fine. It was just one jar that caused problems. Glassfish doesn't like when you deploy glassfish-embedded-all to it. Which makes sense in hindsight. Taking that jar out made everything deploy just fine. I just replace the resource link in my JNLP with a central download location for it.